# Find the value of $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{{4{{\cos }^2}\left( {f\left( x \right)} \right) - 1}}{{1 - {x^2}}}$

Tags: limits

Let  $ f\left( x \right) = f\left( {2x} \right)\forall x \in R$ is continuous and $f(2017)=\frac{\pi}{4}$ then $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{{4{{\cos }^2}\left( {f\left( x \right)} \right) - 1}}{{1 - {x^2}}}$is=_________.

How do I proceed this type of question

There needs to be a functi0n that satisfies  $ f\left( x \right) = f\left( {2x} \right)\forall x \in R$ and $f(2017)=\frac{\pi}{4}$

Comment: $f(x)=f(\frac x {2^{n}}) \to f(0)$ so $f$ is a constant.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:Prove inductively that $$f(2017)=f(\frac{2017}{2^n})$$ Thus taking limits $n\to \infty$, $f(0)=\frac{\pi}{4}$

Finding the limit now is a piece of cake....